# I can't use any commands of custom plugins I installed from git for Cordova VS 2015

Tags: git, cordova, phonegap-plugins, visual-studio-2015

All plugins were installed using the config.xml menu in VS 2015, but when i try to run any function in the index.ts or index.html it just says it can't find the class, so I can't compile. All plugins are installed on the plugins folder and all seem to be in the right place, but I just can't call anything.

However, any plugin installed from the core menu works. Its just customs that I get from git hub that it doesn't show up. They do show up in the "Installed" tab.

An example would be:

```
WifiWizard.getCurrentSSID(ssidHandler, fail);
```

("Error TS2304  Cannot find name 'WifiWizard'.")
[Plugin in the example is from this github](https://github.com/parsonsmatt/WifiWizard)

Perhaps I am just implementing wrong as I am new to Cordova, but I assumed that it should work as easy as those core plugins, just install and it should be recognized by the IDE and show up in intellisense.

Edit: but i did notice that intellisense shows up for some core plugins that I have not installed like `navigator.accelerometer` from "Device Motion".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update 1 for VS 2015 Cordova fixed it.